# Image Segmentation - Berkeley Dataset

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, segmentation

I've been given an image from Berkeley dataset to segmentate. I am an undergrad student and so far I threw everything i know to this thing. But the colors are extremely close. I tried;

- Clustering
- Edge Detection
- Histogram Thresholding

I need suggestions. Which path should I take? I need to segmentate the animals from this picture but I was only able to remove the green leafs.

[image]

Comment: You should consider reading some kind of survey of methods. That is what I do when I start working on something new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at SLICO : http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/177415 .

Superpixels along with graphcut/grabcut methods are quite good at similar segmentation problems. I have had really good results with SLICO and MRFs/Simulated Annealing approaches.

Comment: SLIC was quite useful thank you. I used Peter Kovesi's article and applied SLIC, afterwards I applied DBSCAN clustering for merging superpixels together.

Answer (score 0):

You can try grabcut algorithm. Check this link:
[Interactive Foreground Extraction using GrabCut Algorithm](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_grabcut/py_grabcut.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is also an algorithm i would like to try and Berkeley's website states graphcut algorithms work well with this image. But I applied SLIC + DBScan so that's why I accepted Ameya005's answer.